# IllegalStateException querying SQLite but only in some devices

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I'm using ORMLite to query my database. I have the code below. It works fine on every phone I've tried (Nexus 4, 5, S3). However, it gets an error on HTC One and MotoX.

```
try {
    return Globals.getApplication().getDBHelper().getUserDao().queryForId(id);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
```

Here's the User Dao & class:

```
public Dao<User, String> getUserDao() throws SQLException {
    if (userDao == null) {
        userDao = getDao(User.class);
    }
    return userDao;
}

@DatabaseTable(tableName = User.tableName)
public class User {
    public static final String tableName = "User";
    private static final String TAG = "[User]";
    @DatabaseField(id=true)
    private String id;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "name")
    private String name;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "phone", canBeNull = true)
    private String phone;
}
```

The error is below. When it gets into this state, even if I restarted the app, it would continue to crash.

Any idea on why it only happens to specific phones? Or what causes the database to be in a bad state?

```
        AndroidRuntime  E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                    E  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.leo.android/com.leo.android.ui.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 4 from CursorWind
                       ow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
                    E   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2463)
                    E   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520)
                    E   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
                    E   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1366)
                    E   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                    E   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                    E   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
                    E   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                    E   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                    E   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
                    E   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
                    E   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                    E  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 4 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
                    E   at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetLong(Native Method)
                    E   at android.database.CursorWindow.getLong(CursorWindow.java:565)
                    E   at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getLong(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:75)
                    E   at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:220)
                    E   at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:237)
                    E   at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidCompiledStatement.getCursor(AndroidCompiledStatement.java:163)
                    E   at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidCompiledStatement.runQuery(AndroidCompiledStatement.java:57)
                    E   at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator.<init>(SelectIterator.java:55)
                    E   at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.buildIterator(StatementExecutor.java:245)
                    E   at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.query(StatementExecutor.java:194)
                    E   at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.query(BaseDaoImpl.java:263)
                    E   at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.QueryBuilder.query(QueryBuilder.java:361)
                    E   at com.leo.android.entities.User.getUser(User.java:235)
```

Comment: is it after some scenario or every time the application is run, the crash happens on those phones?

Comment: Weird thing is this only happens during the Sign Up flow but not the Log In flow on these devices. The app becomes unusable when it happens. Even if I restarted the app, it would crash. Any idea what causes a database to be in a bad state? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the DAO and the SQL that causes the issue?

Comment: @Michael: Posted the Use Dao and class. Do you want me the raw sql? The ORMLIte call (findById) is at the top.

Comment: @dannyroa yeah I know, the actual SQL would be helpful as well...

Comment: What version of ORMLite are you using?

Comment: Any chance you are rerunning the application after it was suspended?  Does your sign-up process switch to the web-browser and then back?

Comment: @Gray: I'm using 4.47. We tried using raw sql and still the same problem. When the DB turns into a bad state, restarting the app doesn't fix it.

Comment: Can you answer my 2nd question?

Comment: @Gray:I believe the app tries to restart after the crash. Sign up process does not use WebView. How would using a WebView affect SQlite? Thanks.

Comment: When the application halts and then restarts _without_ being removed, database connections that have not properly been closed can be left around and not reopened.  This can cause double connections to databases and the like.  This can happen when a program is switched to another.  Do you have background server threads that are keeping database connections open?

Comment: @Gray: I don't have background threads. I have a SyncService that runs every 10 seconds but I stop it when the app goes in the background. Is there any way to detect any database connections left opened?

Comment: We switched to Cupboard.

Answer (score 2):

use following code at the place of your query to fetch all data from database

```
 for ex:- 
 select * from tableName where name = "a";
```